# why ansible always replaces double quotes with single quotes in templates?

Tags: docker, jinja2, ansible

I am trying to generate Dockerfiles with Ansible template -  see the role source and the template in Ansible Galaxy and [Github](https://github.com/peruncs/docker)

I need to genarate a standard Dockerfile line like:

```
...
VOLUME ["/etc/postgresql/9.4"]
...
```

However, when I put this in the input file:

```
...
instruction: CMD
value: "[\"/etc/postgresql/{{postgresql_version}}\"]"
...
```

It ends up rendered like:

```
...
VOLUME ['/etc/postgresql/9.4']
...
```

and I lose the " (which renders the Dockerfiles useless)

Any help ? How can I convince Jinja to not substitute " with ' ? I tried  **\"** , **|safe** filter, even **{% raw %}** - it just keeps doing it!

**Update:**
Here is how to reproduce the issue:

Go get the **peruncs.docker** role from **galaxy.ansible.com** or Github (link is given above)
Write up a simple playbook (say **demo.yml**) with the below content and run: **ansible-playbook -v demo.yml**. The **-v** option will allow you to see the temp directory where the generated **Dockerfile** goes with the broken content, so you can examine it. Generating the docker image is not important to succeed, just try to get the Dockerfile right.

```
- name: Build docker image
  hosts: localhost
  vars:
        - somevar: whatever        
        - image_tag: "blabla/booboo"
        - docker_copy_files: []
        - docker_file_content:
             - instruction: CMD
               value: '["/usr/bin/runit", "{{somevar}}"]'
  roles:         
      - peruncs.docker
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: have you tried `| to_json` ?

Comment: I heard about it, but was hesitant since my files are not really json. I will give it a shot, thanks for reminding me.

Comment: Unfortunately it did not work ... to_json creates other problem with stuff like "xxx/yyyy", says invalid namespace.

Comment: Can you update with ansible that you are using? I tried an example just then with the template module and the double quotes were not converted.

Comment: Alec, thanks for trying to help. I updated the issues with easy instructions on how to reproduce it .

Comment: I needed to make some edits to your sample playbook to make it runnable (correcting `loclhost` -> `localhost`, and providing a value for `docker_copy_files`, which seems to be required by peruncs.docker).

Comment: Thanks , I will fix the role tome make it optional

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Something in Ansible appears to be recognizing that as valid Python, so it's getting transformed into a Python list and then serialized using Python's `str()`, which is why you end up with the single-quoted values.

An easy way to work around this is to stick a space at the beginning of the value, which seems to prevent it from getting converted into Python:

```
- name: Build docker image
  hosts: localhost
  vars:
        - somevar: whatever        
        - image_tag: "blabla/booboo"
        - docker_copy_files: []
        - docker_file_content:
             - instruction: CMD
               value: ' ["/usr/bin/runit", "{{somevar}}"]'
  roles:         
      - peruncs.docker
```

This results in:

```
CMD  ["/usr/bin/runit", "whatever"]
```

Comment: Thanks larsks! I will be able to test this later today, but it sounds you solved my problem, I wil lcredit you for that. Do you think I should file an issue with Ansible? Or Jinja?

Comment: I guess maybe against ansible, or maybe ask on their [mailing list](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/community.html#i-ve-got-a-question) first.

Comment: @SamB that seems like a different issue - I can confirm that this problem still exists in ansible 2.1.1.0 (released June 2016) and that issue was closed as "probably fixed" early 2015. The preceding space workaround still works around it.