# How do you set key/value secret in AWS secrets manager using Ansible?

Tags: amazon-web-services, ansible, aws-secrets-manager

The following code does not set the key/value pair for secrets. It only creates a string. But I want to create key/value and the documentation does not even mention it....

```html
- hosts: localhost
  connection: local
  gather_facts: no
  tasks:
    - name: Add string to AWS Secrets Manager
      aws_secret:
        name: 'testvar'
        state: present
        secret_type: 'string'
        secret: "i love devops"
      register: secret_facts
    - debug:
        var: secret_facts
```

Comment: Try setting the string as a json list i.e. `[{"Key": "value"},{"Key2": "value2"}]`

Comment: @ChrisWilliams i replaced where "i love devops" is and it doesnt work, it still creates it in the "plaintext" area and not in the "key/value" area in the console

Comment: So if you use the string above how does it look in the plain text area? Does it match that or does it perform any character replacements etc?

Comment: [{'Key': 'value'}, {'Key2': 'value2'}]  - copied and pasted from the console. When I click the key/value section i see this error: The secret value can't be converted to key name and value pairs

Comment: Hmm, it should be double quotes not single quotes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IF this matches anything like the [Secrets Manager CLI](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/secretsmanager/create-secret.html) then to set key values pairs you should expect to create a key value pair like the below:

```
- hosts: localhost
  connection: local
  gather_facts: no
  tasks:
    - name: Add string to AWS Secrets Manager
      aws_secret:
        name: 'testvar'
        state: present
        secret_type: 'string'
        secret: "{\"username\":\"bob\",\"password\":\"abc123xyz456\"}"
      register: secret_facts
    - debug:
        var: secret_facts
```

Comment: Forgot the escaping, added now

Comment: It still under string not key/value and it looks like this --> [
  {
    "username": "bob"
  },
  {
    "password": "abc123xyz456"
  }
]

Comment: hey! figured it out "{\"username\":\"bob\",\"password\":\"abc123xyz456\"}". this works correctly

Comment: Adjusted can you try now

Comment: Yeah I think you and I figured out at the same time @shan

Comment: Hmm, even this results in single quotes and the described issue for me. I can't find a way this will work!

Comment: Interesting, so this works if you pass a string but it doesn't work if you try and replace the string with a variable. Testing still, but this works:



`secret: "{\"username\":\"myuser\",\"password\":\"mypassword\"}"`



But this does not:



`secret: "{\"username\":\"{{ username }}\",\"password\":\"{{ password }}\"}"`

Answer (score 1):

While the answer here is not "wrong", it will not work if you need to use variables to build your secrets. The reason is when the string gets handed off to Jinja2 to handle the variables there is some variable juggling that goes on which ends in the double quotes being replaced by single quotes *no matter what you do*!

So the example above done with variables:

`secret: "{\"username\":\"{{ myusername }}\",\"password\":\"{{ mypassword }}\"}"`

Ends up as:

`{'username:'bob','password':'abc123xyz456'}`

And of course AWS fails to parse it. The solution is ridiculously simple and I found it here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/32014283/896690

If you put a space or a new line at the start of the string then it's fine!

`secret: " {\"username\":\"{{ myusername }}\",\"password\":\"{{ mypassword }}\"}"`

Answer (score 0):

I hope you find a solution for your problem, but i find in the doc the arguments json_secret to switch with secret_type: and secret:

Something like that:
secret manager can make conversion in k/v and string afert

```
json_secret: 
  url: "{{private_link}}" 
  port: "{{access}}"
  username: "{{item.item.user}}"
  password: "{{item.item.password}}"
  database: "{{database}}"
```